# Best way to start making 360 degre site

Tags: html, css, 360-degrees

Im new at HTML/CSS and i would like to start directly at HTML5 so could someone explain not so wide how does this site works for example
http://www.360langstrasse.sf.tv/page/

Is it loading Images from Server Continually ,is it just re-rendering images or is it playing with Image Positions

PS : The balloons(menu) which are appearing on page like menus how can i achieve that ,should i just change their position using JavaScript?

[EDIT]
http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#how - i just found that plugin ,does it mean this can do the trick ?

Comment: Yes it should certainly be possible to use that jQuery plugin to achieve a similar effect. However, that plugin does not use ajax so images are loaded with the page rather than through ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is continually loading images from the server via some very complex JavaScript.

If you use Google Chrome and open the Developer Tools you can see this happening within the network tab when you scroll on the site.

**Update**

This file is of particular interest:
http://360langstrasse.srf.ch/js/mine/ProgressiveImageSequence.class.js